# Draw and connect objects on html canvas using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, backbone.js

I am currently working on a web application using **Backbone.js**. I need to be able to draw objects in a tree fashion and connect parent to siblings, etc.

There are examples out there that demonstrate drawing objects onto a canvas as well as attaching `hover` and `click` events to each canvas object, but there aren't any implementation examples on how to connect the objects.

For example, say we have a JSON object:

```
{  
  topObject: {
    siblingA: {},
    siblingB: {},
  }
}
```

which would draw something like:
[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction for accomplishing this using **Backbone.js**, or even better, provide an example doing so? I am at a loss as to where I should even begin.

Comment: I take it you've look through http://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams/ ? Check the licences if your project is commercial but many include examples. The paper.js site is particularly good with exampleshttp://paperjs.org/examples/ in the top right corner to edit code

Comment: @Sam0 I have come across that resource and have explored through them all. My problem is that there aren't any examples of implementation accomplishing the same idea as the picture I've provided. The [paper.js examples](http://paperjs.org/examples/) are great, but it would help to find examples connecting the objects in a "tree-like" manor.

Answer (score 0):

Best two I can find are [Flow-svg](https://github.com/rtalbot89/flow-svg) which is based on the SVG.js library and [flowchart.js](https://github.com/adrai/flowchart.js) which is based on Raphaël. Both Git pages have fairly clear examples and documentation code. flowchart.js however has its own shorthand language, whereas Flow-svg has a well structured json system - which isn't too dissimilar to yours and with many styling options. Snippet below :

```js
    flowSVG.draw(SVG('drawing').size(900, 1100));
    flowSVG.config({
     interactive: false,
     showButtons: false,
     connectorLength: 60
    });
    flowSVG.shapes(
     [{
       label: 'tops',
       type: 'decision',
       moveRight: 500,
       text: ['Boss'],
       orient: {
        yes: 'b',
        no: 'r'
         // If there is a next...
         //next: 'r'
       },
       yes: 'siblingA',
       no: 'siblingB'
      }, {
       label: 'siblingA',
       type: 'process',
       text: ['Brother'],
       next: 'end'
      }, {
       label: 'siblingB',
       type: 'process',
       text: ['Sister'],
       next: 'end'
      }, {
       label: 'end',
       type: 'finish',
       text: ['done']
      }

     ]);
```

```html
<script src="http://rawgit.com/rtalbot89/flow-svg/gh-pages/example/svg.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/rtalbot89/flow-svg/gh-pages/dist/flowsvg.min.js"></script>

<div id="drawing" style="margin-left:10px"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you've taken with this! Thank you for the couple libraries to checkout, I plan on looking into both of them.